# Creating BITMAP object from a .bmp image

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a BMP image and I wish to convert it into a Bitmap object in Android. Can anyone explain me how this can be done ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Read the .bmp file

2) Done :)

EXAMPLE:

```
  InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Here's a link to supported bitmap formats:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

<= Includes JPEG (.jpg), GIF (.gif), PNG (.png) and BMP

Comment: Sry, I didnt get your solution . How this code will get the URL of image I wish to use ?

Comment: It will work for *any* input stream.  You could just as easily open a file as a URL.

Comment: I meant how will I specify the input stream. Sorry, I am a newbie in Android, started an hour ago :(

Comment: regarding connection.getInputStream(). I am not getting this one?